# Is this possible to achieve absolute position functionality without using position attribute through css?

Tags: css, outlook, position, absolute

I am creating outlook email. I have created an email system. I have check in all email giants like Gmail, yahoo etc it work perfectly but suddenly when I saw same email in outlook it was shocking that outlook not supports position attribute.

Now, what I want is to achieve same functionality, I have searched on Google but not found a good source to solve issue except this platform to ask question. 
Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Note: I don’t want to do this by placing one div inside other. This not suits my application at all i want things to positioned with respect to corners (width/height).

[image]

Comment: For outlook you'll have to use tables and it's css support is very limited. Have fun! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

outlook does not support `position:`, so perhaps use a table-based solution?

check out these links;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/#css-com_1

Comment: thanks...but i know that outlook doesn't supports position element mentioned in question as well. i am looking for alternative if any.

Comment: No problem but as i said a alternative solution would be a table.

Comment: i don't have anything in mind to achieve that functionality. i have already used tables. but i have no issue with tables/divs i have issue with css position element. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you choose to code your HTML email by yourself (my personal preference) or to use an existing template, there are two fundamental concepts to keep in mind when creating HTML email:

- Use HTML tables to control the design layout and some presentation.
  You may be used to using pure CSS layouts for your web pages, but
  that approach just won’t hold up in an email environment.
- Use inline CSS to control other presentation elements within your
  email, such as background colors and fonts.

Keeping css 1.0 standards in mind will help you a lot when it comes to outlook. [For some other details click here.](http://webdesign.about.com/od/intermediatetutorials/a/html-newsletters.htm) Have fun!

Comment: thanks for your advice bro. but this is not answer to my question.

Comment: I am afraid, this is the only way you will achieve what you want to. We all went through this phase, do not worry! :-/

Comment: Your link is dead!