# Independently align table cell(s) within row without using flex

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two spans within a table cell with content in them that I want to be able to align horizontally independently from each other while staying in the same row.

Currently, I am able to change their alignment together by changing the `text-align` on the `<td>` they are within.

I am working on an editor and would like for users to be able to have more robust options for the custom alignment if possible. Any ideas?

Here is a basic codepen and I also have an image describing the positions I would like. Is this possible with tables and basic CSS? I cannot use flex or most modern CSS because it has to be compatible with Outlook and other desktop email clients.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses so far. I did some searching and it looks like both `position: absolute` and `text-align-last` have minimal support in outlook. See other SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117283/css-text-align-last-doesnt-work-in-html-email) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209305/is-this-possible-to-achieve-absolute-position-functionality-without-using-positi). I think I will be limited to using tables and basic HTML elements. I have updated the title/wording of this post and the codepen to better reflect the problem. Thanks.

[image: Div Positionings]

[Old Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzPQJO)

[New Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoJjXW)

Code from codepen:

```
<table width=100%>
  <tr width=100% valign='bottom'>
    <td id='container'>
      <span class='first'>Hello!</span>
      <span class='second'>World!</span>
  </tr>
</table>

#container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
  /* text-align: left; */
}

.second {
  background-color: green;
  /* text-align: right; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine to me.

```html
    <div id='container'>
      <div class='inline first'>Hello!</div>
      <div class='inline second'>World!</div>
    </div>

    <style>
    .inline {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #container {
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* @This doesn't work, what would? This does*/
    .first {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
    }

    .second {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
    }
    </style>
```

Using `position`, you can change alignments on the x and y axis. This, for example, works.  :)

Comment: This is ok but doesn't work well when elements are positioned below and `position` isn't supported in Outlook. I have updated the question to relate to tables and more accurately reflect what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that. :/

Answer (score 0):

The adjustment of the two elements to the two sides can be achieved using `text-align-last: justify;`, the others with regular `text-align` settings:

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

.first {
  background: red;
}

.second {
  background: green;
}

#container1 {
  text-align-last: justify;
}

#container2 {
  text-align: left;
}

#container3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#container4 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id='container1'>
  <div class='inline first'>Hello!</div>
  <div class='inline second'>World!</div>
</div>
<div id='container2'>
  <div class='inline first'>Hello!</div>
  <div class='inline second'>World!</div>
</div>
<div id='container3'>
  <div class='inline first'>Hello!</div>
  <div class='inline second'>World!</div>
</div>
<div id='container4'>
  <div class='inline first'>Hello!</div>
  <div class='inline second'>World!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I told villager above - this is a fine solution for modern browsers but won't work in the dinosaur that is Outlook. I have updated the question to more accurately reflect what I'm trying to achieve.